# what key=dictionary.get is doing in max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I simply cannot wrap my head around what key = dictionary.get is doing in order to produce the result.

Take this simple dictionary for example:

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

I understand, for instance, that dictionary.get('c') would return 3.  However, using dictionary.get, with no argument, simply returns 'built in method get of dict object'.  Why then does this return something different when used in max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)?

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
print(max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)) # 'c'
```

I've read the documentation but can't understand it...Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Why then does this return something different when used in max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)" It doesn't. The `key` parameter expects a *function*. Do you understand what the purpose of the `key` parameter is?

Comment: Ohhh I missed that, thank you! So key=dictionary.get is basically running .get() on every key in dictionary?

Comment: @jermriddled I think it would be more obvious if you do the following: `dictionary = {'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':1}` (So the max key and max value are different from each other). Now a `print(min(dictionary))` returns 'a' but a `print(min(dictionary, key=dictionary.get))` returns 'c' because one method is looking for the max of the values, and the other is looking for the max of the keys!

Answer (score 1):

`max()` function is to find the max item from the iterable. In your case, the iterable is `dictionary`, which means the *keys* of the dictionary as you will see in

```
for k in dictionary:
    print(k)
```

`max()` also can take an optional `key` callable argument, in which, the max is determined by the value of the return of the callable. In your case, if we find `k` from the iterable, we determine the max value by `dictionary.get(k)`.

If we write this in procedural code, it is:

```
max_output = None
max_value = ? # some correct initial value
for k in dictionary:
   if dictionary.get(k) > max_value:
       max_value = dictionary.get(k)
       max_output = k
return max_output
```

So your line means to find the maximum key from `dictionary` which maximum is defined by the value held in it.